# Use of Getis Ord and Moran's I

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics, moran-index

I have dataset with around thousand geocoded datapoints, each having specific pollutant and its value assigned to it (so it is all in one dataset, some of the datapoints(stations collecting data) are listed several times due to them reporting different pollutants). I would like to check for the spatial correlation of data and literature points me to Moran's I and Getis Ord calculations for this. I believe there are plugins for QGIS that can calculate Moran's I but I did not find one for Getis. Additionally, would somebody be able to explain what is the reasoning for using one or another or is there a need to use both of them when thinking about spatial correlation?

Answer (score 2):

Getis-Ord G measures high/low clustering - so are there any high/low values that are close together.

Moran's I checks to see if there is spatial dependence between values. So basically it measures if there is linear correlation between values and its neighbours.

What is the purpose of checking for spatial correlation? What are you trying to identify? You could use tools like the Moran's I correlogram, where you computer Moran's I at increasingly larger lag distances to see at what point the data is no longer spatially correlated.

You can do a similar thing by assessing the variogram (plotting half the sum of squared differences between points at increasingly larger distances apart). You can vary these methods to look for directional spatial structure as well, but again it all comes down to what you are wanting to describe.